# modify inline node values in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the below XML file. I want to modify only Detail values in this XML file such as Genre, Title, Writer, ISBN. And finally the file should be saved with the modified changes using c#.

```
<Book>
 <LibraryCode>LIB-0001</LibraryCode>

 <BookDetail>
    <Detail  Name="Genre" Value="fiction" />
    <Detail  Name="Title" Value="Book of thrones" />
    <Detail  Name="Writer" Value="King of Thrones" />
    <Detail  Name="ISBN" Value="108y387527" />
 </BookDetail> 
</Book>
```

please suggest me an optimal solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can read you xml file to a string, use System.Xml to treat it, than save it again. Something like this:

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("YourFile.xml")) 
   {
       String line;
       // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
       // the file is reached.
       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.AppendLine(line);
       }
    }
    string xmlString = sb.ToString();

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));

    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Detail");
    foreach (XmlElement no in nodes)
    {
         XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("ISBN");
         attr.InnerText = "12345";
         no.Attributes.Append(attr);
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("YourFile.xml", false))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the below code is working properly and solved my problem.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(FilePath);
XmlNodeList aNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Book/BookDetail/Detail");
foreach (XmlNode aNode in aNodes)
{
  XmlAttribute NameAttribute = aNode.Attributes["Name"];
  XmlAttribute ValueAttribute = aNode.Attributes["Value"];

  if (NameAttribute != null)
  {
    string currentValue = NameAttribute.Value;
    if (currentValue == "ISBN")
     {
        ValueAttribute.Value = ISBN_value;
     }
     //Likewise we can change values of all the inline nodes in XML
  }
}
```